# Contract not found when forking, but is present on remote network

Tags: solidity, hardhat, test, blockchain-fork

I have forked polygon mumbai network in my local project so that I can solve the Ethernaut challenges by writing tests (to improve my understanding of ethers.js, testing, and solving the problems etc)

I thought that forking the network would create a clone with exactly the same state etc as that of the original, but I can't seem to confirm this...

I do this with hardhat.config.js:

```
networks: {
    hardhat: {
      accounts,
      forking: {
        url: "https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/<key>",
        blockNumber: 0,
      },
    },
}
```

And I run the fork locally by running:

`npx hardhat node --fork https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/<key> --port 7545 --verbose`

I have the ethernaut ABI, followed by the ethernaut address, and then my before hook:

```
const ETHERNAUT_ABI = [
  {
    anonymous: false,
    inputs: [
      {
        indexed: true,
        internalType: "address",
        name: "player",
        type: "address",
      },
      {
        indexed: false,
        internalType: "contract Level",
        name: "level",
        type: "address",
      },
    ],
    name: "LevelCompletedLog",
    type: "event",
    signature:
      "0x9dfdf7e3e630f506a3dfe38cdbe34e196353364235df33e5a3b588488d9a1e78",
  },
  {
    anonymous: false,
    inputs: [
      {
        indexed: true,
        internalType: "address",
        name: "player",
        type: "address",
      },
      {
        indexed: false,
        internalType: "address",
        name: "instance",
        type: "address",
      },
    ],
    name: "LevelInstanceCreatedLog",
    type: "event",
    signature:
      "0x7bf7f1ed7f75e83b76de0ff139966989aff81cb85aac26469c18978d86aac1c2",
  },
  {
    anonymous: false,
    inputs: [
      {
        indexed: true,
        internalType: "address",
        name: "previousOwner",
        type: "address",
      },
      {
        indexed: true,
        internalType: "address",
        name: "newOwner",
        type: "address",
      },
    ],
    name: "OwnershipTransferred",
    type: "event",
    signature:
      "0x8be0079c531659141344cd1fd0a4f28419497f9722a3daafe3b4186f6b6457e0",
  },
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "contract Level",
        name: "_level",
        type: "address",
      },
    ],
    name: "createLevelInstance",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "payable",
    type: "function",
    payable: true,
    signature: "0xdfc86b17",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "owner",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "address",
        name: "",
        type: "address",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
    constant: true,
    signature: "0x8da5cb5b",
  },
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "contract Level",
        name: "_level",
        type: "address",
      },
    ],
    name: "registerLevel",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
    signature: "0x202023d4",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "renounceOwnership",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
    signature: "0x715018a6",
  },
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "address payable",
        name: "_instance",
        type: "address",
      },
    ],
    name: "submitLevelInstance",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
    signature: "0xc882d7c2",
  },
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "address",
        name: "newOwner",
        type: "address",
      },
    ],
    name: "transferOwnership",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
    signature: "0xf2fde38b",
  },
];

ETHERNAUT_ADDRESS = `0xe04f955e4Cf9858F8f8d60C09aBf16DF23D4672b`;

before(async () => {
  const ethernaut = await ethers.getContractAt(
    ETHERNAUT_ABI,
    ETHERNAUT_ADDRESS
  );
}
```

However, I get the error:

`0xe04f955e4Cf9858F8f8d60C09aBf16DF23D4672b is not a contract account.`

This address most certainly is a contract account, as it is the Ethernaut contract on Mumbai, seen here:

https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xe04f955e4Cf9858F8f8d60C09aBf16DF23D4672b

Clearly this is a contract account on Mumbai testnet, so why isn't it on my fork of Mumbai testnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```js
      forking: {
        url: "https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/<key>",
        blockNumber: 0,
      },
```

`blockNumber: 0` means you're forking at block number `0` ([docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks#pinning-a-block)), so of course the contract isn't deployed yet.

I believe removing it should fix your problem:

```js
      forking: {
        url: "https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/<key>",
      },
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I removed this and started my node with: `npx hardhat node --fork https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/<key> --port 7545 --verbose --fork-block-number 28885869` Unfortunately it is still not working... same error as above

Comment: I am starting my test with: 

`hh test ./test/1-fallback.js` 

Should i be passing in any flags with that command?

Comment: If I run the command `hh test ./test/1-fallback.js` without starting my node using the above command, i get the same errors as above, so maybe i am missing a flag when i run my test command?

Comment: I got it working - I had two `forking: {...}` entries in my `hardhat.config.js` and removed the blocknumber as suggested. Thank!

Comment: Nice, glad it worked!